# .NET and html pages auth management

Tags: .net, html, authentication

I have absolutely no knowledge of .NET but am tasked to think/solve a small issue. I have a web site written in .NET which authenticates users before allowing them in. Now there is a new directory containing static html pages that must be controlled using the same auth session. I want to achieve this without having to convert the html pages into .NET because the team working on that is not .NET aware. Also I don't want to have a web server specific auth configuration as that would mean the current auth session cannot be used. Is there a way to solve this? Ideally I would want to have some equivalent of a filter in java (though the filters are activated only if its a jsp) which checks the directory and checks the auth session. So my web app directory setting is this way --

App/
|   --- All .NET
|   --- htmldir/*.html

I want all of these to use the same auth management as the .NET app.

Any inputs are appreciated. Please point me to the documents or books to read up on.

- Pav

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Mono implements system.web.routing but some versions of .NET does.  You might be able to use that to forward all requests to app/html through a page that checks for login and then if they pass send the html through with a response.write.  However I think the best way would be if you could drop the webserver specific requirement and use the webconfig.  Normally IIS is used with .NET unless you are using MONO.

Comment: I do not want to drop the webserver specific requirement because if I have a different authentication setup for the html pages then the user would be prompted for login again even though he is logged into the .NET site. Also I have to write code to make the web server use the same login and password as the .NET site somehow.